# Show two things side by side using catimg (like in neofetch)

Tags: bash, scripting, cat

I am trying to create something like neofetch does using bash.

I want to show one image on the right and one ascii art (using the cat << EOF myascii EOF command)
So that I can show a logo and a text on the other side.

I want to use it as my login welcome screen when I ssh some of my machines.

So I was able to show the ascii art by doing :

```
cat << EOF

 _____         _   
|_   _|       | |  
  | | ___  ___| |_ 
  | |/ _ \/ __| __|
  | |  __/\__ \ |_ 
  \_/\___||___/\__|
                   
                   

EOF
```

And showing my image using `catimg myimage.png`

However I try to show them both side by side. I tried using pr.
`pr -m -t <(catimg) <(cat mytestfile.txt)` but it doesn't work and it cuts my ascii art.

It's the same using the paste command.

Was anyone able to do it. If yes how ?
My ascii art is quiet long too so without it to be cutted it would be awesome.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: try `paste <(catimg myimage.png) <(cat mytestfile.txt)`. I believe that;s not possible without smart handling and filtering ascii escape sequences and coloring generated by catimg.

Comment: Note that [neofetch](https://github.com/dylanaraps/neofetch/blob/master/neofetch) is a [tag:bash] script! You could read them to see how it work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Produce txt file by *merging* ouput of `catimg` and `figlet`

Instead of real *merge*, I will simply put both output at correct place by using [*ANSI escape code*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)

```
{
    mapfile aa < <(figlet -w40 $text)
    printf "%s" "${aa[@]}"
    catimg -w40 "$image" |
        sed "\$!s/^/\o33[40C/;1s/^/\o33[${#aa[@]}A/"
} >outputfile.txt
```

[image: figlet-catimg]

This could be written as a function:

```
mkTextImage() {
    local aa width=${COLUMNS} prcent=50 text image lwidth rwidth ffont
    while [ "${1::1}" == "-" ] ;do
        case $1 in 
            -w) shift;width=$1;shift;;
            -p) shift;prcent=$1;shift;;
            -f) shift;ffont="-f $1";shift;;
        esac
    done
    text="$1" image="$2"
    printf -v lwidth %.0f $(
         bc -l <<<"$width/100*$prcent")
    rwidth=$((width-lwidth))
    mapfile aa < <(figlet -w$lwidth $ffont $text)
    printf "%s" "${aa[@]}"
    catimg -w$rwidth "$image" |
        sed "\$!s/^/\o33[${lwidth}C/;1s/^/\o33[${#aa[@]}A/"
}
```

And reversed:

(Nota: This work while *catimg* length stay bigger than *figlet* length)

```
mkImageText () { 
    local aa fl width=${COLUMNS} prcent=50 text image lwidth rwidth ffont
    while [ "${1::1}" == "-" ] ;do
        case $1 in 
            -w) shift;width=$1;shift;;
            -p) shift;prcent=$1;shift;;
            -f) shift;ffont="-f $1";shift;;
        esac
    done
    image="$1" text="$2"
    printf -v lwidth %.0f $(bc -l <<<"$width/100*$prcent")
    rwidth=$((width-lwidth))
    mapfile aa < <(catimg -w$lwidth "$image")
    printf "%s" "${aa[@]}"
    printf "\e[$((${#aa[@]}-1))A"
    mapfile fl < <(figlet -w$rwidth $ffont "$text")
    printf "\e[${lwidth}C%s" "${fl[@]}"
    printf "\e[$((${#aa[@]}-${#fl[@]}-1))B"
}
```

[image: catimg-figlet]

From there, regarding your comment: try using `42%` of *80 columns width* for image:

```
mkImageText -f small -p 42 spongebob.png "Sponge Bob"
```

or

```
mkTextImage -f small -p 58 "Sponge Bob" spongebob.png
```

Will render:

[image: Gif animation of both commands on 80x25 terminal]

Then you could try using `-f smblock` option, or modify functions to use `toilet` instead of `figlet`...

More complete version on my website: [mkImageText.sh](https://f-hauri.ch/vrac/mkImageText.sh.txt)

Comment: Ah very nice, but I am not able to inverse them to have the image on the right side.

Is it also possible to make it for the text of sponge bob fit on one line?

Comment: I am trying to make it work in a script and in a simple test.sh bash script it isn't working. Am I missing something?

Comment: Care to use `#!/bin/bash` as shebang! ... And replace `local` by `declare`

Comment: ... if still not working, try to replace `$width={COLUMNS}` by `width=80` or `width=$(tput cols)`

Comment: Ah, perfect tput cols did it! Thanks for your awesome help!

Comment: There is a full [mkImageText.sh](https://f-hauri.ch/vrac/mkImageText.sh.txt), using `-r2` option of `catimg` and offering `-t` switch for toggle `Text <-> Image`,