# Drawing to screen and keeping image intact while using dialog

Tags: bash, dialog, framebuffer, stty

I am running on Raspbian (Debian 11) lite, with CLI only.
I use a bash script with dialog to navigate a menu and perform bash actions.

I would like to "mimic" the Raspbian start screen, when an image is shown above (or below) the lines of code running in the foreground.

For a visual representation, I attached an image of the intended result.  The programmer already works, I'm just trying to give it an extra added flavor.
[Intended Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoj44.png)

Here is a snippet of what I tried with explanations:

```bash
fbi -a --noverbose -t 5 -1 /opt/splash.png
export DIALOGRC=/home/pi/.dialogrc
stty -echo
clear
(sleep 1; killall -9 fbi) &
fbi -a --noverbose /opt/splash.png
stty rows 60
```

FBI shows the full screen logo for 5 seconds, then exits gracefully.
I load my configuration file for Dialog
I clear the screen
I start a delayed killer to forcefully close fbi, thinking it would keep the image loaded on the framebuffer (like throwing garbage at the device directly, using something like `cat /dev/urandom >/dev/fb0`)
I then set the amount of usable rows to less than the screen resolution (67 standard, 60 manually set) hoping it would prevent anything from clearing the bottomn 7 rows, keeping that part of the image intact

I think I'm going in the wrong direction, but at this point I've been researching this for 2 days and I can't find any help beyond installing an actual GNU+, which I'd like to avoid.

I like that I can remotely use the program through SSH, so if possible it wouldn't write to the FrameBuffer itself, but that would be acceptable as well.

I've installed fbi (Frame Buffer Imageviewer) and posted to:
default TTY
forced TTY1 (the console on local screen)
dynamic TTY (whatever device is running the script)
directly to /dev/fb0

It shows the image (except on ssh, but that's fine), but when I kill the process (using either 9 for a force, or 15 for gracefully) the screen just shows the image and is completely unresponsive.

Comment: For showing image in console (even through ssh) you could consider `catimg`! [Show two things side by side using catimg (like in neofetch)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64967229/1765658)